# Show ProgressDialog after Back Button Press

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, progressdialog

I have pressed `Back Button` either after `navigation start` or after `route shown`.

I am working on `Fragment`. `View` be like in order: A-B-C-D in the `Fragment`. And, `Back Press` work flow is like : B:A, C:B:A, D:C:B:A.

But, I want to use `progress bar` after every `back press` before displaying the screen where I came after `back press`.

I have used the following code in `onBackPress` method:

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    if (hasNavigationStarted) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeFragment.this.getActivity());
        alert.setTitle("Really quit?");
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to exit navigation?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                isDrivingModeOn = false;
                navigationManager.stopNavigation();
                corLDriveInfoContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mapView.clearAllOverlays();

                progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressBar.setMessage("Loading ...");
                progressBar.show();
                progressBar.setCancelable(false);
                if (isDrivingDirectionsOn) {
                    showDriveInfoForDrivingDirection();
                    rlDrivingDirections.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((ToolbarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                    if (drivingDirectionDestPoint != null) {
                        mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
                        addAnnotation(drivingDirectionDestPoint);
                        mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLongitude(), drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLatitude()));
                    }
                    if (drivingDirectionStartPoint != null) {
                        mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
                        addAnnotation(drivingDirectionStartPoint);
                    }
                } else if (latestDriveInfoPlace != null) {
                    setSearchViewShown(true);
                    addAnnotation(latestDriveInfoPlace);
                    mapView.setZoom(MapUtils.DEFAULT_ZOOM_VALUE);
                    mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(latestDriveInfoPlace.getLongitude(), latestDriveInfoPlace.getLatitude()));
                    searchItem.expandActionView();
                    searchView.setQuery(latestDriveInfoPlace.getName(), false);
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        alert.show();
        return true;
    } else if (isRouteShown) {
        isDrivingModeOn = false;
        navigationManager.removeRouteCalculationViews();
        mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
        isRouteShown = false;
        corLDriveInfoContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (isDrivingDirectionsOn) {
            rlDrivingDirections.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((ToolbarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            if (drivingDirectionDestPoint != null) {
                mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
                addAnnotation(drivingDirectionDestPoint);
                mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLongitude(), drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLatitude()));
            }
            if (drivingDirectionStartPoint != null) {
                mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
                addAnnotation(drivingDirectionStartPoint);
            }
        } else if (latestDriveInfoPlace != null) {
            setSearchViewShown(true);
            addAnnotation(latestDriveInfoPlace);
            mapView.setZoom(MapUtils.DEFAULT_ZOOM_VALUE);
            mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(latestDriveInfoPlace.getLongitude(), latestDriveInfoPlace.getLatitude()));
            searchItem.expandActionView();
            searchView.setQuery(latestDriveInfoPlace.getName(), false);
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
        return true;
    } else if (isDrivingDirectionsOn) {
        isDrivingDirectionsOn = false;
        rlDrivingDirections.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        corLDriveInfoContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setSearchViewShown(true);
        searchItem.collapseActionView();
        drivingDirectionDestPoint = null;
        drivingDirectionStartPoint = null;
        atvDestination.setText("");
        atvStart.setText("");
        hideKeyboard();
        ((DrawerViewInterface) getActivity()).showHamburgerIcon();
        ((DrawerViewInterface) getActivity()).unlockDrawer();
        mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Update code**

I have implemented the `ProgressDialog`.

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
progressBar.setMessage("Loading ...");
progressBar.show();
progressBar.setCancelable(false);
```

But, Where do I use the `dismiss()` method here after returning the screen when `back press` ? What can be done to solve this issue ?

Comment: What are you trying to use the progress dialog for?

Comment: I use map, so after back press map take time to refresh, so I want to use Progress Dialog. Something like: this kind of operation: `mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
                        addAnnotation(drivingDirectionDestPoint);
                        mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLongitude(), drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLatitude()));
                    ` happen. So, i want to overcome of it.

Comment: You dont have to implement that onBackPress. If you have an AsyncTask in each fragment.. Start the dialog on onPreExecute() and dismiss it on PostExecute().

Comment: So, this is a bad idea to implement Progress Dialog in `on Back Press`?

Comment: Yes.. Since on backPress you dont actually know how long you have to wait for data to load on a new fragment. Using the progress dialog in onPreExecute before network call and dismissing it in onPostExecute after the network call is the best way to go. This way you ll also be able to display progress (like Loading.... 90%).

Comment: See the sample answer below.

Comment: Let me know if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You want to show your ProgressDialog when some task (that takes some time to finish) starts, and dismiss it when the task finishes.

I can't see such task in your code snippet, but if there is one I believe it provides an API to register a listener in which you should show and dismiss your ProgressDialog.

If you don't have a task that takes some time to finish, it is not good practice to show the ProgressDialog. Try a different approach. Maybe some animations (eg. fade out views, change data, fade in views).

Comment: There are few task like: `mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
                        addAnnotation(drivingDirectionDestPoint);
                        mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLongitude(), drivingDirectionDestPoint.getLatitude()));
                    ` after back press in view by view.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in each fragment:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressBar.setMessage("Loading ...");
        progressBar.show();
        progressBar.setCancelable(false);


    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

    //Network call to refresh map data


         }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
       if(success)
            progressBar.dismiss();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the progress in onResume and dismiss it in the onMapReady callback.

In your fragments onResume:

```
if(mMap == null){
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressBar.setMessage("Loading ...");
    progressBar.show();
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
}
```

and in your onMapReady:

```
if(progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()){
    progressBar.dismiss();
}
```